# Código responsivo para dispositivos mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, layout-responsivo, html5-video

Boa tarde!

Gente, existe alguma forma de adequar um código como o abaixo para que fique responsivo de forma geral em qualquer dispositivo mobile?
Todas as formas que tentei ajustando os atributos widht e height não ajustaram o código, principalmente o video que ficou bem ruim de visualizar no Mobile.

```html
<div class="div">
  <div class="div-2">
    <div class="builder-columns div-3">
      <div class="builder-column column">
        <div class="div-4">
          <div class="div-5">
            <div
              code='<iframe\n  width="560"\n  height="315"\n  src="https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/videos_site_customic/CustomicDezAnos_Proteja_seu_mundo.mp4?controls=0&amp;&amp;autoplay=1&amp;mute=1;&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=83xyE4zJggw;"\n  title="YouTube video player"\n  frameborder="0"\n  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"\n  allowfullscreen\n></iframe>\n'
              class="div-6"
              data-name="div-1"
            >
              <div>
                <iframe
                  width="560"
                  height="315"
                  src="https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/videos_site_customic/CustomicDezAnos_Proteja_seu_mundo.mp4?controls=0&amp;&amp;autoplay=1&amp;mute=1;&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=83xyE4zJggw;"
                  title="YouTube video player"
                  frameborder="0"
                  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                  allowfullscreen
                ></iframe>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="builder-column column-2">
        <div class="div-7" data-name="div-2">
          <picture>
            <source
              srcset="
               https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498.webp?format=webp&width=100   100w,
                https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498.webp?format=webp&width=200   200w,
                https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498.webp?format=webp&width=400   400w,
https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498.webp?format=webp&width=800   800w,
                https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498.webp?format=webp&width=1200 1200w,
               https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498.webp?format=webp&width=1600 1600w,
               https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498.webp?format=webp&width=2000 2000w,
                https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets%2F986e144735c045578f7903725872417c%2Ffc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498
              "
              type="image/webp"
            />
            <img
              loading="lazy"
              src="https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498"
              srcset="
                https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498?width=100   100w,
                https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498?width=200   200w,
                https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498?width=400   400w,
                https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498?width=800   800w,
                https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498?width=1200 1200w,
                https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498?width=1600 1600w,
                https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498?width=2000 2000w,
                https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498
              "
              class="image"
            />
          </picture>
          <div class="builder-image-sizer image-sizer"></div>
        </div>
        <a href="https://customic.com.br/colecoes" class="a" data-name="a-1">
          Conheça nossas coleções
        </a>
        <div class="div-8"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div-9"></div>
<div class="div-10"></div>
<style>
  .div {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .div-2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .div-3 {
    display: flex;
  }
  @media (max-width: 999px) {
    .div-3 {
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: stretch;
    }
  }
  .column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    line-height: normal;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 999px) {
    .column {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  .div-4 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 640px) {
    .div-4 {
      margin-bottom: -1px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
  }
  .div-5 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    .div-5 {
      padding-right: 40px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 640px) {
    .div-5 {
      height: auto;
      flex-grow: 0;
      width: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      align-self: stretch;
      min-height: 200px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  }
  .div-6 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    height: auto;
    align-self: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    .div-6 {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 640px) {
    .div-6 {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      align-self: center;
      min-height: 133px;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }
  .column-2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    line-height: normal;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 999px) {
    .column-2 {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  .div-7 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
    min-width: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding-right: 0;
    max-width: 317px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    .div-7 {
      display: flex;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 640px) {
    .div-7 {
      max-width: 209px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      display: flex;
    }
  }
  .image {
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .image-sizer {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 43.669999999999995%;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-size: 0;
  }
  .a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    appearance: none;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    color: white !important;
    border-radius: 96px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    align-self: stretch;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    .a {
      display: flex;
      margin-top: 32px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 640px) {
    .a {
      width: auto;
      align-self: stretch;
      height: auto;
      flex-grow: 0;
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: auto;
      padding-top: 15px;
      display: flex;
    }
  }
  .div-8 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .div-9 {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 202px;
  }
  .div-10 {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 483px;
  }
</style>
<script>
  (() => {
    const state = {};

    let nodesToDestroy = [];
    let pendingUpdate = false;

    function destroyAnyNodes() {
      // destroy current view template refs before rendering again
      nodesToDestroy.forEach((el) => el.remove());
      nodesToDestroy = [];
    }

    // Function to update data bindings and loops
    // call update() when you mutate state and need the updates to reflect
    // in the dom
    function update() {
      if (pendingUpdate === true) {
        return;
      }
      pendingUpdate = true;

      document.querySelectorAll("[data-name='div-1']").forEach((el) => {
        el.setAttribute("scriptsClientOnly", false);
      });

      document.querySelectorAll("[data-name='div-2']").forEach((el) => {
        el.setAttribute("lockAspectRatio", false);
      });

      document.querySelectorAll("[data-name='a-1']").forEach((el) => {
        el.setAttribute("openLinkInNewTab", false);
      });

      destroyAnyNodes();

      pendingUpdate = false;
    }

    // Update with initial state on first load
    update();

    // Helper text DOM nodes
    function renderTextNode(el, text) {
      const textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
      if (el?.scope) {
        textNode.scope = el.scope;
      }
      el.after(textNode);
      nodesToDestroy.push(el.nextSibling);
    }
  })();
</script>
```

Aguardo O Help De Vocês!!

Forte Abraço a comunidade!

Answer (score -2):

Fiz algumas modificações no seu HTML e CSS, o motivo do video ficar sempre pequeno é que você está trabalhando com métricas estáticas, isso prejudica a responsividade, tenta utilizar métricas dinâmicas, e para coisas simples como essa sua página aconselho utilizar o Bootstrap.

Se ainda tiver dúvida pode falar.
Espero ter ajudado.

```
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 ">
            <div code='<iframe\n src="https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/videos_site_customic/CustomicDezAnos_Proteja_seu_mundo.mp4?controls=0&amp;&amp;autoplay=1&amp;mute=1;&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=83xyE4zJggw;"\n  title="YouTube video player"\n  frameborder="0"\n  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"\n  allowfullscreen\n></iframe>\n'
                class="ratio ratio-16x9" data-name="div-1">
                <iframe
                    src="https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/videos_site_customic/CustomicDezAnos_Proteja_seu_mundo.mp4?controls=0&amp;&amp;autoplay=1&amp;mute=1;&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=83xyE4zJggw;"
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex flex-column ">
            <div data-name="div-2">
                <picture>
                    <source srcset="
                https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498.webp?format=webp&width=100   100w,

              " type="image/webp" />
                    <img loading="lazy"
                        src="https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498"
                        srcset="
                https://www.comercial.customic.com.br/news/imagens_site_customic/assets_986e144735c045578f7903725872417c_fc4b5059c6e64c10a9966e7887503498?width=100   100w,
               
              " class="image" />
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="btn p-3 itens-end">
                <a href="https://customic.com.br/colecoes" class="conheca" data-name="a-1">
                    Conheça nossas coleções
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .image {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .image-sizer {
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 43.669999999999995%;
        pointer-events: none;
        font-size: 0;
    }

    .conheca {    
        padding:15px 25px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        color: white;
        border-radius: 96px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
</style>
```